# Big Query - Date Comparison

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to retrieve from a table that I have created in BigQuery that has many columns one of them being Date.

The type is DATE and I want to retrieve only records that are between two dates.

Please see below my code.

```
SELECT ExpakAccounts.Account As Account1, ExpakAccounts.description As Name, collection.Col_Dpt As Col_Dpt, collection.Own_Dpt As Own_Dpt, collection.Service As Service, COUNT(collection.Parcels) AS Cons, SUM(collection.Amount) AS Amount, collection.Filename As Filename, collection.Date AS Date 
FROM `rawdataset.ExPakAccounts2` AS ExpakAccounts 
INNER JOIN `rawdataset.collection_2018` AS Collection ON ExpakAccounts.Account = collection.Account
WHERE ExpakAccounts.Account = collection.Account AND collection.Cat = 100 AND (Col_Dpt <> Own_Dpt) AND (collection.Service = 32 OR collection.Service = 68) AND (DATE(Date) >= '2018-07-30' AND DATE(Date) <= '2018-08-06')
GROUP BY Account1, Name, Col_Dpt, Own_Dpt, Service, Cat, Filename, Date;
```

**Error Message**

`No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: DATE`

Comment: Error message No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: DATE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Date BETWEEN '2018-07-30' AND '2018-08-06` in your `WHERE` clause. That will return rows for which the date is between 2018-07-30 and 2018-08-06.

Also, if your field `Date` is already of type `DATE` using `DATE(Date)` will throw the following error `No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: DATE. Supported signatures: DATE(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]); DATE(DATETIME); DATE(INT64, INT64, INT64)` as the function date only supports `TIMESTAMP` or `INTEGER`.

Instead, you will just use your `Date` field as is (without a `DATE` function) in your where clause.

If your `Date` field is of type string you can use `CAST(Date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-07-30' AND '2018-08-06` in your `WHERE` clause.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date) is more information regarding Standard SQL functions in BigQuery